# Boxplot including outliers in R, make the whole ranges being compared.

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics, regression, boxplot

I am comparing several values using R, they are 8 variables stored in 1000 length vectors. That means, 1000*8 matrix, 8 columns represent 8 variables.

Then I call

```
boxplot(test),
```

I got like:
The mean values of 8 variables are very close to each other. Which makes the comparison and interpretation very hard. Can I include all the outliers in my plot ? Then the whole range would be easier to compare ? Or any other suggestions could be given to distinguish these variables ?

Comment: It is hard to understand exactly what you are asking. Boxplots will by default plot outliers, so what are you lacking? What are the variables you are trying to compare?

Comment: I havent got enough reputation to post a picture, but, the variables are the same drawn from different simulations with different parameters, can I just simply include all the outliers ? I dont know how to change the default.

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't really help matters. `boxplot()` will already plot all your outliers, so what exactly is the problem? And how do you want to compare your variables?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1HubY3HsuxaeHZHRi1Ud0V4dm8/edit?usp=sharing @StephanKolassa Would you mind to look at the picture in the link ? You will understand the problem, how to compare and interpret the 8 variables ?

Comment: The plot is broken, can you please re-upload?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1HubY3HsuxaeHZHRi1Ud0V4dm8/edit?usp=sharing  @StephanKolassa Can you see it ? It is in google drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the boxplot in question (since the OP doesn't have the rep to post pictures):
[image: boxplots]

It looks like the medians (and likely also the means) are pretty much identical, but the variances differ between the eight categories, with category 1 having the lowest and 8 the highest variance. Depending on the real question involved, these two pieces of information (similar median/mean, different variance) may already be enough.

If you want a formal significance test whether the variances are equal, you can use [Hartley's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartley%27s_test) or [Bartlett's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartlett%27s_test) test. If you want to formally test equality of means with unequal variances (so ANOVA is not appropriate), look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816948/parametric-anova-with-unequal-variances).

Comment: Kplassa,  Thanks for your answer, but you see the outliers ? Can the boxplot include all the outliers ? then the mean and median will be different possibly ?

Comment: Oh, I think I start to understand what you mean. You want the boxes to extend the entire range of your data? You can do that using `rect()`, with the `ybottom` and `ytop` parameter set to the min and max of each column, instead of `boxplot()`, adding horizontal `lines()` for the median. But I don't see how that would be more helpful than the boxplots. And of course the mean & median wouldn't change if you only *plot* your data differently.